# Select range in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, numbers, between

I have a sql database that have InvoiceNumber column

Now i need to select range between two numbers, but i don't know what happened.

I've tried "Between" and "<= , >=" Statements but the results are same.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQQdV.png)

[My query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3ZoI.png)

For example:
If i need range between "13000" and "13020" and there is number "1301"
its appear in results.

Comment: Are the invoice numbers text?

Comment: Please [don't post images of code or data](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Yes, its nvarchar(50)

Comment: Are they of numeric type though?  You'll need to conver them to numeric values to acheive what you want.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav If i convert it to "int", then will i lose my data in that column?

Comment: No, you'd say where cast(x as int) between 1000 and 2000, you're only converting for where purposes.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Yes, Its Worked, you save me, Thank you soo much

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in a nvarchar(50)? Use the right datatype - int

Comment: @SteveFord, Yes you are right, I will correct that in my next project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to conver your value in the where clause to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is becouse your InvoiceNumber is a varchar. As @Nathan_Sav mentioned, you need to convert it to something comparable, for example bigint.

```sql
select * from SalesInvoice where convert(bigint, InvoiceNumber) >= 13000 and convert(bigint, InvoiceNumber) <= 13020 and Status = 'True'
```

Comment: Yes, Its my fault when creating a table, Your query worked great also, Thank you soo much.

Comment: Only use `bigint` if you use > 2 or 4 billion, use `int` instead.

Comment: Our invoice numbers are 10 digits, starting with last two digits of actual year (so now 22). Since `integer` range is 2147483647, this year it would cause problem. I'm glad we had `bigint` in our database :) But I understand, for this scenario `int` is sufficent.